# I'm trying to make it so my tkinter input field is first checked amongst a file and then if it's not there, is added

Tags: python, tkinter, file-handling

I've tried to make a functioning sign up page, and whilst my input can be added to the file, I first want to make sure that the input of `username` does not already exist in the file. The function which checks this is as follows:

```
forename = forename_entry.get()
surname = surname_entry.get()
username = username_entry.get()
password = password_entry.get()

with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
    end_of_file = False
    while not end_of_file:
        existent_username = file.readline().strip()
        if existent_username == username:
            additional_info_text.config(text="Username already exists, try choosing a different one",
                                        font=("Ariel", 10))
            submit_data.config(state="disabled")
            end_of_file = True
        else:
            with open("data.txt", "a") as edit_file:
                edit_file.write(forename + "\n")
                edit_file.write(surname + "\n")
                edit_file.write(username + "\n")
                edit_file.write(password + "\n")
                edit_file.write("" + "\n")
                end_of_file = True
```

Keep in mind that `submit_data.config(state="disabled")` is there to check if my code was functioning in checking if it was there or not, but it did not. I don't understand where i am going wrong, but it is most likely in my first check. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is better to store all the user information in one line instead of four lines because if the input username is the same of any other fields in the file, it will be identified as existing user as well.  Also saving password as plain text is not recommended.  Using database instead of text file is also recommended.

Answer (score 0):

try `if username in existent_username:`

Comment: The checking is evaluated as `True` even `username` is "abc" and `existent_username` is "abcd".